Signature of Matrices
I need help with the following question:
Provide matrices $ S \in \mathbb{C}^{3 \times 3}   such\ that\ for\ all \ i, j \in \{1, 2, 3\}\  s_{ij} \neq 0 , and\ that\ the\ associated\ Hermitian\ sesquilinear\ form\  \sigma_S\  has\ the\ signature:
(i)  \text{sgn}(\sigma_S) = (3, 0, 0). $
I know that i have to find a Matrix with 3 positive eigenvalues. Let A be the diagonalmatrix with these eigenvalues. Furthermore A=B^TSB. I dont know how i can find the Matrix B.
For example i found $S=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1&1\\1 & 2 &1\\1&1&2\end{bmatrix} which\ has\ eigenvalue\ 4\ and\ 1\ but\ how\ do\ i\ find\ the\ B\\ such\ that\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0&0\\0 & 1&0\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}=B^T*S*B?$

Please don’t use
images instead of typing your formulas

Please use MathJax to formulate the question, images are not easily searchable.

Also, try something. You need to do some work.

You don't need to find $B$.  The matrix $S$ and its eigenvalues $(4,1,1)$ are enough.

and what is the reason why it is enough? So i know that S is similar to a diagonal matrix with positive values?
